# CCRotateBy And CCRotateTo not working with ARM64 Devices correctly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, ccrotateby

```
   const float gravity = 9.8f;

    float L = 0.01f;

    double CurrentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    double angle = 40.0f * sin(sqrt((gravity/L)*CurrentTime));

    id rotation = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:angle];
    id reverseRotation = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:3.0 angle:sprhang.rotation];
    [sprhang runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotation, reverseRotation , nil]]];
  // [sprhang runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotation,reverseRotation], nil]]];
     [self addChild:sprhang];
```

This is my code to show pendulum effect for a sprite, it works fine with old devices which is not ARM64, btw i had done some code changes in CCAnmation Interval class of CCRotationBY and CCRotationTO to support ARM64 devices. and it is working fine .. but my issue is when i put above code, first action rotation is working fine ,but reverse action showing sudden movement back to previous position then again good first rotation and when the time of reverse movement it shows sudden movement toward the initial position,,i hope any one will help me in this.

Comment: Try CCRotateBy( + angle), for reverse CCRotateBy( - angle)

Comment: @Guru Thanks for your reply,, sorry i didn't understand your comment..can you explain please? Thanks in advance